# visual webpart custom properties not working

Tags: custom-web-part-property

I am trying to create visual webpart custom properties but it is not appearing.

my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="VisualWebPartProject2016.R9ToDoWebPart.R9ToDoWebPart, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" />
      <importErrorMessage>$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="Title" type="string">My To Do List</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">My Visual Web Part</property>
        <property name="RootR9Url" type="string">http://w2k12sp04:44444</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>


using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;

namespace VisualWebPartProject2016.R9ToDoWebPart
{



    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class R9ToDoWebPart : WebPart
    {
        private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/15/VisualWebPartProject2016/R9ToDoWebPart/R9ToDoWebPartUserControl.ascx";

        private string _r9Url = String.Empty;

         [WebBrowsable(true),
        WebDisplayName("RMT+ rooturl"),
        WebDescription("RMT+ rooturl"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
        Category("RmtPlus")]
        public string RootR9Url
        {
            get
            {
                return _r9Url;
            }
            set
            {
                _r9Url = value;
            }
        }


        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
            Controls.Add(control);
            ((R9ToDoWebPartUserControl)control).RootUrl = RootR9Url;
        }





    }
}



using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

namespace VisualWebPartProject2016.R9ToDoWebPart
{
    public partial class R9ToDoWebPartUserControl : UserControl
    {
        private string _rootUrl = String.Empty;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public string RootUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return _rootUrl;
            }
            set
            {
                _rootUrl = value.TrimEnd(new char[]{'/'});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]` is missing on your partial class. Also ordering may be a issue but I am not sure about that. I am giving you a fully functional code snippet where I implemented webpart custom properties. Please update your code as per my below code. Let me know whether it works or not.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;

namespace Survey.WP_Survey {
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public partial class WP_Survey: WebPart {
        private string _r9Url = String.Empty;
        [WebBrowsable(true)]
        [WebDescription("RMT+ rooturl")]
        [WebDisplayName("RMT+ rooturl")]
        [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
        public string RootR9Url {
            get {
                return _r9Url ;
            }
            set {
                _r9Url = value;
            }
        }


        public WP_Survey() {}

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            try {
                CreateQuestion();
            } catch (Exception ex) {}

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error message:  Line 8:  <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="R9ToDoWebPartUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="VisualWebPartProject2016.R9ToDoWebPart.R9ToDoWebPartUserControl" %>

Comment: Show your full code in your question. Are you developing farm or sandboxed solution

Comment: I have updated my code. It is a Farm solution.

Comment: ohhh..... You copy and paste my whole code!! Class name and constructor should be different in your case

Comment: I didn't checked that. I'll change it and try than.

Comment: yeah ....... do that properly. otherwise you will get error again

Comment: I don get this part    " public WP_Survey() { }" what should I write there insted of that?

Comment: replace WP_Survey with your class name

Comment: Ok I have fixed it now, I was little slow yesterday.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30467/discussion-between-atish-dipongkor-and-abc).